# How Can I Pipe the Sed Command?

Tags: sed, pipe, mysql, gunzip

I have a bash script that imports wordpress dbs for me pretty reliably, but one of my sites came from a former wordpress multisite, therefore the database includes DEFINERS within the database that prevents the following code from executing correctly

```
gunzip -c $destination_path_to_wordpress/folder/db-export.sql.gz | mysql -u $destination_db_user -p$destination_db_pass $destination_db_name
```

The above results in `ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 3224: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SET_USER_ID privilege(s) for this operation`

If I manually export the db then run `` sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' -i db-export.sql `` and then attempt to import the db then I can successfully import the db, search-replace the user name, and site it live.

**Question:**
What is the correct syntax to to combine my current db import command and the sed command that gets rid of the definer problem? something like the following is what I would like to achieve:

clearly incorrect, but you get the gist...

```
gunzip -c $destination_path_to_wordpress/folder/db-export.sql.gz | `sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' -i db-export.sql | mysql -u $destination_db_user -p$destination_db_pass $destination_db_name
```

any tips?

thanks

Comment: Do you REALLY want to have backticks in your sed command? Post sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton yes almost certainly in this instance. MySQL uses backticks as quote marks for table and column names that don't adhere to standard SQL naming conventions. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/2344631)

Comment: @roaima thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want `sed` to process the data from the `gunzip` rather than from a file. Omit the file name and it will happily read from *stdin* (i.e. from the `gunip`) and write to *stdout* (i.e. the `mysql`).

For readability I've split this over three lines. It will still work like this but you can join the lines together as one if you really prefer:

```
gunzip -c "$destination_path_to_wordpress/folder/db-export.sql.gz" |
    sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' |
    mysql -u "$destination_db_user" -p"$destination_db_pass" "$destination_db_name"
```

Comment: You just made my morning. Worked flawlessly. thanks